# How to insert row in table with foreign key to itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have [table](https://picasaweb.google.com/TheAteist/ERD?authkey=Gv1sRgCMapkN6EzLa6Mg#5609625343557306466) that has foreign key for itself. Column **parentid** is foreign key and it **cannot** be NULL.

if I do`INSERT INTO mytable(name) VALUES('name')`, so it says that can't insert NULL to **parentid**. BUT, what value I can set to it if no row was inserted yet?!

How I can write script that will add row to this table?

Thank you

Comment: Either use the id of the top level(s) as parentid or remove the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: @Lieven: he can't use the id, it's not assigned yet and there are, to my knowledge, neither of deferrable fkeys (which would allow a trigger to kick in) nor serial manipulation functions (which would allow to set the parent_id as part of the insert) in sql-server.

Comment: @Denis - the `ID` in the table definition is a simple `int`, not a sequence. I assume OP assigns the `ID`. If so, he can insert a record with the `Parentid` = `ID`.

Comment: I dunno... if the insert statement is anything to go by, it's an auto incrementing field. But if you're correct, then indeed he should set them both to their expected value.

Comment: Do you always insert one row, or also a set of rows? If you insert a set of rows, all your rows reference themself or some of the rows reference other rows?

Comment: @Alex, I insert set of rows and in most cases there will be only 1 row with reference to itself while other will have reference other rows

Comment: @Lieven, how I can write script with **parentid=id**? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @theateist - you need to show how you maintain those references in the regular cases, when rows reference other rows. In other words how do you know that row #2 from your dataset references row #1.

Comment: in 1 table I have the rows **34 'name1' 34**, **35 'name2' 34**   (id,name,parentid) and I want to copy them to other table.

Comment: @theateist - I've been away but it seems your question to me has been adequately answered by other posters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trick: Have a dummy row with a dummy key, say 99999. Insert with this as the FK, and then change the FK to its real value. And do it in a transaction.

Comment: Or a dummy row with ID 0. :-)

Comment: I would choose a dummy row with `id = -1, parentid = -1`

Comment: @ypercube, how you will do this if **id** is auto incrementing field?

Comment: @theateist: I'll post an answer.

Comment: It is funny how sometimes the answer is marked. Some people actually put some effort to find a solution to the problem. They making and testing their solutions. I definitely could answer something as quick as 'dummy key', but this would pose a bunch of future questions. After a few iteration of questions I made a solution that does exactly what was asked in the question with a working script. Spent quite a lot of time for asking questions back and forth and implementing the solution. Well... this is something rather discouraging about Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Alex, I really wanted to accept 2 answers: yours, Erik, Denis and ypercube. But I can't mark all of them. I choose Erik's answer because in order to insert dummy row I use `set identity_insert maytable on` that is s a per-connection and won't affect other connections running against this table while altering table will affect other connections. I know that I didn't mentioned any constraints and this is my fault. But your answer helped me with my 2nd part of the problem. If you want I can make new post with reference to your answer. I'm sorry that it happened. I'm really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the NOT NULL constraint, as it is an inappropriate constraint. If you do not have a ParentId then the value is NULL and should be allowed. Creating a dummy row just to have a dummy parentid creates unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the value is "known" at the time of the insert - it's the IDENTITY value on one of the rows being inserted. It's just that SQL Server doesn't provide any way to specify that value. IDENTITY is the problem, not the NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the FK in charge. 
Then do the insert
Then do an update with the new (generated?) PK-ID into the Self-FK-Field
Then Enable the FK back.

LIke so:

```
ALTER TABLE [Client] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Client_MainClient]
INSERT INTO Client VALUES ...
@ClientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
IF @IsMainClient=1  
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Client] 
    SET MainClientID = @ClientID 
    WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
END 
ALTER TABLE [Relatie] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Relatie_Relatie]
```

Answer (score 2):

How to make a dummy row with both `id` and `parentid` equal to `-1`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    parentid int  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parentid) REFERENCES mytable(id)
)  ;


SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON ;      <-- this allows you to insert the 
INSERT INTO mytable(id, parentid)     <-- auto incremented identity field
    VALUES (-1, -1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable OFF ;

SELECT * FROM mytable ;

| id | parentid |
| -1 | -1       |
```

If you have many data from other tables that you want to transfer into this table, you can set the IDENTITY_INSERT variable to ON, insert the data and then set it to OFF again.

But as others said, it might be better to just remove the `NOT NULL` constraint from the `parentid` field.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the column to allow null then set the fk to the new identity and enable not null again.

This should work, though maybe there is a better way

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
 name varchar(50) not null,
 parentid int not null
)
go
alter table mytable
add constraint FK_mytable_parentid FOREIGN KEY ( parentid ) references mytable(id)

ALTER TABLE mytable alter column parentid int null;

insert into mytable(name)
select 'test'

update mytable
set parentid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
where id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

ALTER TABLE mytable alter column parentid int not null;

select * from mytable
drop table mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you already have id before inserting and you can't insert it because identity field isn't letting you to.

Like you mentioned in your comment:

> in 1 table I have the rows 34 'name1'
>   34, 35 'name2' 34 (id,name,parentid)
>   and I want to copy them to other table

First table

```
create table Table1
(
    id int not null primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    parentId int not null
)

insert Table1
values
    (34, 'name1', 34),
    (35, 'name2', 34)
```

Second table:

```
create table Table2
(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    parentId int not null foreign key references Table2(id)
)
```

Copying data from the first table to the second one:

```
set identity_insert Table2 on

insert Table2(id, name, parentId)
select *
from  Table1

set identity_insert Table2 on
```

**[Update]**

If the second table already has values then:

```
alter table Table2
    add oldId int null

alter table Table2
    alter column parentId int null
go

insert Table2(name, oldId)
select name, id
from  Table1

update tt3
set parentId = tt2.id
from Table2 tt3
    join Table1 tt1 on
        tt1.id = tt3.oldId
    join Table2 tt2 on
        tt1.parentId = tt2.oldId

alter table Table2
    drop column oldId

alter table Table2
    alter column parentId int not null
```

Comment: I didn't mentioned, because I thought it's obvious, that **Table2** is not necessary empty. It can have some rows. So, what if there are already rows with ids 34 & 35? Therefore, I don't think I can use this

Comment: @theateist - not at all obvious. You should strive to give *all* relevant information but nothing more when asking a question. This was relevant information <g>.

Answer (score -1):

Don't reference an IDENTITY column as a self-referencing foreign key. Use an alternative key of the table instead. I guess you are using IDENTITY as a surrogate key but every table ought to have a natural key as well, so the IDENTITY column shouldn't be the *only* key of your table.