# Code first Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF Code First database. Here I have an Entity "Relatie" that has a Parent ID (MoederRid) which is nullable. When we create the database we create a default Relation where the Parent is itself, this is a business rule. When we try to save the changes we get:

```
"Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."
```

We have been searching google but no answers found. Anyone have a clue?

Class:

```
  public partial class Relatie : CreateAT
{
    public Relatie()
    {
        Gebruikers = new HashSet<Gebruiker>();
        Contactpersonen = new HashSet<Contactpersoon>();
        RelatieBestanden = new HashSet<Relatie_Bestand>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int GeslachtEnumID { get; set; }

    public virtual EnumATCode GeslachtEnum { get; set; }

    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int? MoederRID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MoederRID")]
    public virtual Relatie Moeder { get; set; }
}
```

Adding on Configuration:

```
private void AddRootRelatie(FrameworkModel context)
    {
        //Add a root relatie. All relations are a member under the root
        var relatie = context.Relaties.SingleOrDefault(m => m.PublicID == FrameworkModel.ROOT_RELATIE_GUID);
        if (relatie == null)
        {
            relatie = new Relatie()
            {
                PublicID = FrameworkModel.ROOT_RELATIE_GUID,
                Naam = "Root",
                GeslachtEnumID = (int)GeslachtEnum.O
            };
            relatie.Moeder = relatie;
            context.Relaties.Add(relatie);
        }
    }
```

I have tried some of the optioned in: [How to insert row in table with foreign key to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090283/how-to-insert-row-in-table-with-foreign-key-to-itself) But unfortunately did not do the trick for me.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: off course, see above :)

Comment: *"that has a parent ID which is not nullable"* But `MoederRID` is indeed `nullable`. You'd better keep it `nullable` and don't try to make parent itself, because EF cannot handle such scenario, especially with autogenerated IDs.

Comment: Excuse, I mistyped. It is nullable, but has to be filled because of business rules. sorry about the confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert row in table with foreign key to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090283/how-to-insert-row-in-table-with-foreign-key-to-itself)